# Can you sell turnips in another town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Can you take turnips safely to another town and sell them?  I know they are sensitive to changes in time.

I imagine if I travel to the town of someone who changes around the time on their system, that the turnips will spoil?

What if I travel to a friends town and our clocks are off by a minute or two?  Will they spoil then?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this in fact one of the best ways to sell turnips as it vastly improves your chances of finding a town with a high selling price. Reese will still tell you the turnip prices and allow you to sell them in the other town.

I don't believe the time of the other person's game really matters; I played with someone in a (significantly) different time zone to sell my turnips. When I arrived my turnips were perfectly fine.

The way turnips spoil is when you go *back* in time, which the game checks. The game can't really know who's time traveling if you join an online game. I'm unsure if going to a town that is several *days* different would affect anything, but my guess would be no. Going backwards in time and adjusting the clock at the main menu are the two ways the game seems to know you've fiddled with the clock.